# Variable pasada de php a javascript no muestra todos los caracteres

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo esta funcion en un boton

```
"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='CrudNotas(".$row['rut_alumno'].")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></button></td>"
```

la cual cuando reviso el boton, me aparece esto

```
    onclick="CrudNotas(12664999-8)"
```

después cuando recibo la variable en javascript lo hago así

```
    function CrudNotas(str) {
    //resto del código
    }
```

pero cuando imprimo la variable str, me muestra esto 12664991.

la verdad que asumo que debe ser la forma en que recibo la variable en javascript, pero no lo sé con certeza, de todas maneras, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta forzando a que lo pase como `String`:

```
"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='CrudNotas(\"".$row['rut_alumno']."\")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></button></td>"
```

Al parecer lo que pasa es que recibe el parametro como `Number`s, interpreta el guión (-) como un operador aritmetico de resta y realiza la operacion:

`12664999 - 8 = 12664991`

Para que esto no suceda, debes enviar el parámetro como texto (`String`) y asi lo interprete como tal.

Pd: solo agrego `\"` para que, en el HTML generado por PHP, se muestre

`"<td>
  <button
    type='button'
    class='btn btn-primary'
    onclick='CrudNotas("12664999-8")'
  >
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'>
  </button>
</td>"`

Comentas cualquier duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso era, pero disculpa que te moleste, ¿Cual es la función de los \ ? pd: igual estaba pensando eso, que lo pasaba como numero y no string, pero no sabía que hacer, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Es para poder usar `"`anidados dentro de otros ". Ejemplo: en PHP: `echo "\"Hola\""` se traduce a `"Hola"` en HTML